# why i receive the body content mail duplicated when i use php://stdin?

Tags: php, parsing, email

I have a postfix server redirecting all incomming mail into a php script

but the body contents of the mail appears duplicated, looks:

```
--000e0ce03cf6d06b0c04c67595d4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

why
show
this
duplicated?

--000e0ce03cf6d06b0c04c67595d4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

why<div>show</div><div>this</div><div>duplicated?</div>

--000e0ce03cf6d06b0c04c67595d4--
```

i have sended this mail using gmail with this body content:

```
why
show
this
duplicated?
```

why appears the mail two times? (and one in html :S)

how can i get only one? 
thanks!

Comment: Presumably one is for text-only clients, and the other for HTML-compatible clients.

Comment: That's exactly it. Email clients can choose (or let you choose) to display either plain text or HTML emails. Because of this, most major email servers / clients send the email in both formats.

Comment: how can i see which must i choose of two?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code returns the same sort of separator, one method might be to do the following:

```
// Get separator
$mail_pieces = explode("\n", $mail);
$separator = $mail_pieces[0];

// Separate email
$mail_pieces = explode($separator, $mail);
$text_mail = $mail[0];
$html_mail = $mail[1];
```